# Using prelink on manually loaded libraries? (like Java native libraries)

Tags: linux, java, dynamic-linking, elf

As far as I can tell, [prelink](http://linux.die.net/man/8/prelink) can only works with dynamic libraries which an executable declares it needs at compile time (the libraries that can be found with [ldd](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ldd+1)).  It doesn't seem to include dynamic libraries which are manually loaded by the executable, like plugins or (in my particular case) Java native libraries.  Is there any way to force prelink to cover these sort of libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `prelink` on an ELF binary it will only inspect the binary itself and its dependencies (as referenced in the ELF `.dynamic` and `.dynstr` sections).

You should be able to use:

```
prelink --libs-only libone.so libtwo.so [...]
```

If one library is dependent on another you may need to specify these together on the same command line (i.e. if they are not in the normal linker path).

*However*, an important part of pre-linking is being able to determine the best place to load *every* library for a process, it is possible you will not gain the full benefit of prelinking by doing libraries in isolation. This should not happen as long a both of these are true:

- you use the shared cache (`/etc/prelink.cache`) so that all libraries get a unique base
- you do not use the `-m` (conserve memory) when prelinking

Confirm the operation was successful with

```
prelink --print-cache
```